# select everything from the first '{' until the last '}'

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to create a **regex to extract the string between the first `{` and the last `}` from this string:**

> @base64Binary3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��{"topic":"/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/usap-devgru-BBB-interfaces-resgrp/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/BBBdgdevstor","subject":"/blobServices/default/containers/coloradoAAAready/blobs/SIU-S13_2019-5-29
>   16.26.11_27319.HL7","eventType":"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated","eventTime":"2019-06-20T17:10:20.5025763Z","id":"ab0f7xxxxxxx08b-278fa906f76d","data":{"api":"PutBlockList","clientRequestId":"xxxx6-92a6-7a87xx2be32b","requestId":"xxxxx0000","eTag":"0xxxxxD2AEC9","contentType":"application/octet-stream","contentLength":1368,"blobType":"BlockBlob","url":"https://BBBdgdevstor.blob.core.windows.net/coloradoAAAready/SIU-S13_2019-5-29
>   16.26.11_27319.HL7","sequencer":"0000000000000000000000000000019C0000000000969f41","storageDiagnostics":{"batchId":"a01x7f5-0785x256"}},"dataVersion":"","metadataVersion":"1"}

The resulting string would be:

> {"topic":"/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/usap-devgru-BBB-interfaces-resgrp/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/BBBdgdevstor","subject":"/blobServices/default/containers/coloradoAAAready/blobs/SIU-S13_2019-5-29
>   16.26.11_27319.HL7","eventType":"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated","eventTime":"2019-06-20T17:10:20.5025763Z","id":"ab0f7xxxxxxx08b-278fa906f76d","data":{"api":"PutBlockList","clientRequestId":"xxxx6-92a6-7a87xx2be32b","requestId":"xxxxx0000","eTag":"0xxxxxD2AEC9","contentType":"application/octet-stream","contentLength":1368,"blobType":"BlockBlob","url":"https://BBBdgdevstor.blob.core.windows.net/coloradoAAAready/SIU-S13_2019-5-29
>   16.26.11_27319.HL7","sequencer":"0000000000000000000000000000019C0000000000969f41","storageDiagnostics":{"batchId":"a01x7f5-0785x256"}},"dataVersion":"","metadataVersion":"1"}

**How do we select the text inside of the first '{' through the last '}' ?**

Comment: This way `{(.+)}` with dot-all modifier: `(?s){(.+)}`

Comment: that matches the first group?

Answer (score 1):

Won't this regex do it for you?

```
{.*}
```

Regex is inherently greedy by default, so it will search for the biggest match which satisfies the condition, which sounds like what you want.